# Does the single responsibility principle apply to functional programming?

Tags: javascript

I have a class framework I wrote in JavaScript which emulates classes.  The library is written in a functional style.  But the application code is written in an OOP style.

One SE user complained that I did not follow the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) as defined in SOLID.

But b.c. the library code is functional based, do I need to worry about this?

Here is the [actual code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39345/a-package-for-classes-and-ajax-v2).

Is there a fix I can use?

Comment: Who complained? Could you link the comment? Or at least cite it if it was deleted?

Comment: `actual code` link is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Someone] complained that I did not follow the single responsibility principle[, but as]  the library code is functional based, do I need to worry about this?

Yes, you should worry. "Functional" is not an excuse for bad code disposition; modularity is relevant for code quality. Especially if you build a Class framework, OOP principles apply.

> Is there a fix I can use?

I haven't read the code entirely, but it seems you might separate "class setup" from "ajax". An extensive answer to this question should be posted on codereview, however. You might include your worries about SOLID in your question there.